# Erro ao comparar dado do banco de dados com campo vazio de formulário

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Preciso verificar se já existe um número de documento cadastrado para não repeti-lo. No entanto, o campo *Documento* permite nulo, então há um erro quando comparo um valor do banco de dados com um valor null do meu formulário. O que fazer para que a verificação não retorne erro se o tal campo do formulário contiver valor null?

***Aqui eu retorno todos os registros do banco de dados***

```cs
var pontoAtendimentoRecuperados = RecuperarTodos(identidadeAtual);
```

***Aqui eu comparo se algum dos dados trazidos do banco é igual ao conteúdo do campo do formulário***

```cs
var verificaDocumentoExistente = pontoAtendimentoRecuperados.Where(p => pontoAtendimento.Documento.Equals(p.Documento) && pontoAtendimento.Id != p.Id);
```

O erro ocorre na 2ª linha do código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o erro que está ocorrendo?

Comment: @CypherPotato inclui a imagem que representado o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de fazer a comparação é necessário veridicar se o valor não é nulo.

```
var verificaDocumentoExistente = pontoAtendimentoRecuperados.Where(p => p.Documento != null && pontoAtendimento.Documento.Equals(p.Documento) && pontoAtendimento.Id != p.Id);
```